# How to Change /swagger to /help in Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I'm making an api using asp.net web api 2. I'm using swagger as my documentation tool and binding it by using XML. Now, I want to change

```
http://localhost:1230/swagger
```

to

```
http://localhost:1230/help
```

I have tried to use mapping on the WebAPIConfig.cs such as

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "help_ui_swagger",
            routeTemplate: "help",
            defaults: null,
            constraints: null,
            handler: new RedirectHandler(SwaggerDocsConfig.DefaultRootUrlResolver, "help/ui/index"));
```

It displays a 404 error.

I have also try custom routes [check here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#custom-routes). None seems to be working. So my question is How to Change /swagger to /help in Web API 2

Comment: Are you using Swagger-Net ? from nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger-Net/

Comment: If you are you can just set a routeTemplate in the SwaggerConfig.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
    app.UseSwaggerUI(s => {
        s.RoutePrefix = "help";
        s.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My App");
    });
```